# How to resize blob image from php?

Tags: php, image, blob

i tried to add width and height but nothing happened
Here is the code i used
        '
            ">

```
        <div class="product-image">


            <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,<?php 

        echo base64_encode($value['image']);?>"

                 >
            </div>


        <div><strong><?php echo $product_array[$key]["name"]; ?></strong></div>
        <div class="product-price"><?php echo "$".$product_array[$key]["price"]; ?></div>
        <div><input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" size="2" /><input type="submit" value="Add to cart" class="btnAddAction" /></div>
        </form>
    </div>
<?php
        }
}
?>'
```

it shows like this http://www.ya-techno.com/up/uploads/1429701817181.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add it on `<img>` tag:

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,<?php 
    echo base64_encode($value['image']);
?>" style="width:150px">
```